# How to access FB Page's new metric "are talking about this"? FQL? Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FB makes this EdgeRank metric Public (shown on every page) - now how to access it to collect stats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked the Facebook team about this a couple of weeks ago; it seems it was overlooked at the time and they would look into it.  I just checked out the Graph API today and it appears to be in there now!  Here is a quick way to request the data from the Graph API and have it return a JSON formatted result set:

If you want just the count of talking about you can use this format:
https://graph.facebook.com/[PageID or Page Name]?fields=talking_about_count

**Examples:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/techcrunch?fields=talking_about_count
https://graph.facebook.com/8062627951?fields=talking_about_count
```

**Returns:**

```
{
   "talking_about_count": 11937,
   "id": "8062627951"
}
```

You can also combine this with other fields:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/techcrunch?fields=name,category,likes,talking_about_count
```

Returns:

```
{
   "name": "TechCrunch",
   "category": "Company",
   "likes": 364886,
   "talking_about_count": 11937,
   "id": "8062627951"
}
```

Hope this helps,
-Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul. I found the same talking_about_count is accessible via FQL query to "page" table :)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook calls this "Stories"...  Here's how you get it:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/insights/page_stories/day?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

So, you will replace PAGE_ID with the page ID you want to gather the data from...  and then ACCESS_TOKEN with the access token.

You can also change the /day? to either /week?  or /days_28?   to gather that data specifically...

Other options for the story telling insights are:

page_stories
page_storytellers
page_stories_by_story_type
page_storytellers_by_story_type
page_storytellers_by_age_gender
page_storytellers_by_country
page_storytellers_by_locale

Hope that helps!

-Nick

Comment: Thanks Nick, but this Info is not Public - Page Admin must give your app a permission for Insights... so it's Private data, looks like FB  decided to hide that data from others (((